# Ember Data belongsTo can see parent but hasMany is a zero length array

Tags: ember.js

I have a custom serializer and will not bore you with the details.  Anyway, for `hasMany` relationships I want to fetch the data in a separate query.

For example, when I fetch a "Load" the vehicles relationship will be null in the payload.  Then later, if needed, I fetch the "Vehicles" for this load `/vehicles?loadId=12`.  I can see in Ember data that the vehicle relationship is properly hooked up to the load, however, when I look at the load, it has a 0 length array.

Can anyone give me a hint on how I might go about adding the relationship to the vehicle model?  I can supply the serializer if required.

```
var Load = DS.Model.extend({

    ...

    vehicles  : DS.hasMany('vehicle')

});

var Vehicle = DS.Model.extend({

    ...

    load : DS.belongsTo('load')

});
```

Comment: My first thought is that if you want to do lazy loading on your relationships, you should consider using `{ async: true }` (See http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-an-async-relationship-async-true-vs-async-false/4107/10).

Comment: My second thought is that for setting up the inverse data load, maybe you need to use an Explicit Inverse? (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.html#toc_explicit-inverses)?  I'm guessing that probably isn't your issue, though.  I suspect that Ember Data is simply looking for a response from your server that includes the loadId in the Vehicle.  If it gets that, then it links up, if it gets null, then not.  So, the fact that you're getting these vals one at a time may have something to do with it.  The { async } bit may help.

Comment: @JoshPadnick I will checkout out both those options thanks.